# Trigger action when reaching a target div in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, scroll

I am outputting a result set with PHP and MySQL, each result wrapped in a DIV. A JavaScript function triggers an action as soon as the user scrolls to the bottom of the browser window.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
    trigger_funtion();
  }
});
```

Each item (class ".item") of the PHP result is placed into a general wrapper DIV (class ".results") containing all items.

How can I change this function above so that the action is triggered as soon as the user "scrolls" or "arrives" at the last DIV which was created from the result set, rather than when he hits the bottom of the browser window?

I have tried the following, but it does not work

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if  ($(window).scrollTop() == $(".results .item:last")){
    trigger_funtion();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [.position().top](http://api.jquery.com/position/) and I suggest to use >= rather than == since you cannot rely on the numbers being equal

```
if  ($(window).scrollTop() >= $(".results .item:last").position().top)
```

or

```
var winHeight = $(window).height(); // viewport 
if  ($(window).scrollTop()+winHeight >= $(".results .item:last").position().top)
```

Here is the code for when the last item hits the top

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/6x8W8/)

```
$(function() {
  var $item = $(".results .item:last"); // cache element  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var itemTop = $item.position().top-10;  // subtract some pixels from the  item 
    var winScrollTop =$(window).scrollTop();
    window.console && console.log(winScrollTop,itemTop); // remove when happy
    if  (winScrollTop>=itemTop) { 
      window.console && console.log("reached!",winScrollTop,itemTop); remove when happy
      $item.html("REACHED!");
    }
  });
});
```

and here for when it hits the bottom

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/X6YHf/)

```
$(function() {
  var $item = $(".results .item:last"); // cache element  
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var itemTop = $item.position().top-10;  // subtract some pixels from the  item 
    var winScrollTop =$(window).scrollTop();
    var winHeight = $(window).height();  
    window.console && console.log(winScrollTop,itemTop); // remove when happy
    if  (winScrollTop+winHeight>=itemTop) { 
      window.console && console.log("reached!",winScrollTop,itemTop); // remove when happy
      $item.html("REACHED!");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mplungjan for the quick answer! However this tends to trigger only when the last element reaches the browswer top. How can I make it so that the function is triggered as soon as the last item comes up into the browser window from the bottom? Imagine it as a long list of items but as soon as the last one comes into view in the browser, the data should continue to load, like in endless scrolling

Comment: Thanks mplungjan! However I would need it to work that when the "last item" comes into view at the bottom, since now I need to pass all that white space before the last item hits the top, so I tried replacing everything that says "Top" with "Bottom" like so: "$item.position().bottom-10;" or ScrollBottom, but it does not work (I am not good with Java)...

Comment: Please see update. And note that JAVA is not JavaScript

Comment: I think in this case .offset().top would work better, as he wants to compare this distance to the window scrollTop ?

Comment: I have just uploaded the code to http://rainerbrunotte.com/scroll and it does not work? How come it works in jsfiddle but not on my own server?

Comment: Good question. I do not even see the console log. Perhaps you need to change the `https://` to  `//`